# Is it possible to do by Komodo Macro, if so how can I do it?

Tags: macros, komodoedit

I have the nearly 300 pages, as well all the pages contains 4no.s of slides and 4no.s of thumb for them. I need to copy the text what is inside of the `<h1>` tag, and I need to past in the image's alt text with just name, name with front, name with back, name with detail... so as well the page's title should as well the same as `<h1>` text..

I use the komodo editor. if this is possible to using Javascript / jQuery then that would be fine. How can I write the komodo macro for this?

Any expert..? any good idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No. Here are a few tools better suited for the job:

- [awk](http://chiranth.blogspot.com/2007/02/using-awk-to-parse-html.html)
- [Powershell](http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/parsing-linkedin-html-pages-with-powershell/)
- [lynx](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1/lynx/)